# is there any way to extract the X element from a IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Tried with:

```
listPacchetti[2]
```

but it doesnt works at all. In fact I should do this code :

```
IList<SomeObject> listPacchetti = (
    from SomeObject myso in SomeObjects
    select myso)
    .ToList();

int randInd = r.Next(1, listPacchetti.Length);

var temp = listPacchetti[2];
```

using an IEnumerable.

Any other workaround/further way? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can the [ElementAt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or [ELementAtOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.